# Unable to Change User Licenses with system admin access

Tags: user, access

I have system admin access and I am unable to change the user licenses in Salesforce. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community.  Use [edit] and elaborate with screen shots of where this fails and what you observe